# How do you iterate on first N elements of a container?

Tags: c++, loops, vector, set

I have created a set of pairs in C++ to hold potentially colliding pairs of particles for a simple particle simulation as follows:

```
std::set<std::pair<int, int>> uniquePairs;
```

Once populated I want to iterate through it ONLY for the live particles in the simulation to check the distances between them for interaction later. I can iterate through the complete set like so...

```
std::set<std::pair<int,int>>::iterator it;

for (it = uniquePairs.begin(); it != uniquePairs.end(); ++it) 
{
    std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
}
```

BUT, this will throw up a vector 'out of range' error since I would be trying to access particles that are not yet alive. Therefore I want to be able to access the list UP TO the same number of live particles .. i.e N = particles.size().

Please help,

Many thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking, but I don't see how, in the code you've shown, a vector out of bounds error could occur. There are no vectors in the code shown, you iterate over a range in a straight forward way and print some `int`s.

Comment: How could we know what is a *live particle* for you?

Comment: Are you trying to iterate your set while adding or removing pairs?

Comment: `for (const auto& p : uniquePairs) { std::cout << p.first << std::endl;}` is even more succinct to iterate over the set.

Comment: Unless there is more to your for loop than what is shown, or you have a thread that is modifying the contents, then your iterator should not be experiencing an out of bounds event. Even if 'alive/dead' means that the pair<int,int> has not yet been initialized with your desired values, it should still have accessible elements inside of it, unless you were storing pointers rather than actual objects.

Comment: @Jarod42 Shouldn't be `endl` there though

Comment: Why is a set throwing vector errors? Please present your [MCVE] rather than some unrelated made up thing!

Comment: Thank you everyone - answer accepted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not absolutely clear in the question, If the question is, 'How to iterate on first N elements of a container?', below is the way to do it.

```
void foo(std::set<std::pair<int,int>>& uniquePairs, int N) {
    auto it = uniquePairs.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << std::endl;
        ++it;
        assert(it != uniquePairs.end());
    }
}
```

CC: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/tSHQYP

Comment: better to break than assert, to really have **up to** N and not just N.

Comment: Use `'\n'` in a loop, not `endl`. You can `flush` at the end if you must (though I wouldn't recommend it)

Comment: Great Balki! Exactly what I was looking for - to iterate on the first N elements of a container for my purpose.